# Bibliography and Sitography citing are mixed up

Tags: biblatex

Im pretty new to Latex and im working on writing my thesis and while I was working on it, I stumbled upon a problem where my citing wont be in order, I don't mind if they are in order or not until and unless they're there, but the problem which is quite disturbing is that the numbers are mixed between them.
I have the bib file separate and I've imported to my main file. idk how that works here, like grouping i guess, but I hope you understand what I'm trying to ask. I wanted to Split Bibliography and Sitography, and I want other than the @online citations numbered after all the other citations are numbered, if someone could help me with this, this would be great!

PS. Im using Overleaf online

```
%-EM-Stirring by HK-Moffatt
@article{hkmoffatt,
author = {Moffatt, Keith},
year = {1991},
month = {05},
pages = {1336-1343},
title = {Electromagnetic stirring},
volume = {3},
journal = {Physics of Fluids - PHYS FLUIDS},
doi = {10.1063/1.858062}
}
%Mattia.
@article{mattia,
author = {Guglielmi, Mattia},
year = {2017/18},
%month = {05},
pages = {126},
title = {Optimization of Pulsed Magnetic Field Application for Electromagnetic Stirring during the Continuous Casting},
 }
@online{totalmateria,
title = {Electromagnetic Stirring},
url = {https://www.totalmateria.com/page.aspxID=CheckArticle&site=kts&NM=411},
urldate = {2013-05-16},
}
\usepackage[backref=true]{biblatex}
\begin{document}
\section{Citation}
Citing from a paper:\cite{hkmoffatt} 
Citing from a website: \cite{totalmateria} 
Citing from a paper: \cite[p.~11]{mattia}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
\printbibliography[nottype=online, title=Bibliography]
\printbibliography[type=online, title=Sitography]
\end{document}
```

I want the Bibiliography to be numbered first, only after that should the Sitography start.
[image]

Comment: your example seems to be a mix starting as a bib file and then a fragment of tex with no `\documentclass`

Comment: this isnt the full document, i have the bib file separate, the main file separate and the chapters etc separate, I just had the problem with the numbering of citation, and I think David understood what I was trying to say, sorry that I'm a bit unclear of what I posted!

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but with the standard `biblatex` settings you won't need the `p.~` in `\cite[p.~11]{mattia}`: If you say `\cite[11]{mattia}` `biblatex` can automatically detect that you are talking about a page number and adds the "p." for you. If you want to add the bibliography to the table of contents, it is usually recommended to use the `heading` option and not `\addcontentsline`. Remove the `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}` and call `\printbibliography` as `\printbibliography[nottype=online, title=Bibliography, heading=bibintoc]`

Answer (score 1):

If you add the missing lines to your example so that it can be run, it gives the warning

```
Package biblatex Warning: Split bibliography detected.
(biblatex)                Many simple split bibliography setups with
(biblatex)                non-overlapping bibliographies benefit from
(biblatex)                setting 'defernumbers=true'.
(biblatex)                See the documentation for details.
(biblatex)                This warning can be suppressed with
(biblatex)                '\BiblatexSplitbibDefernumbersWarningOff'.
```

don't ignore warnings! if you add `defernumbers=true` then the output is

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backref=true,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{zz.bib}
\begin{document}
\section{Citation}
Citing from a paper:\cite{hkmoffatt} 
Citing from a website: \cite{totalmateria} 
Citing from a paper: \cite[p.~11]{mattia}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
\printbibliography[nottype=online, title=Bibliography]
\printbibliography[type=online, title=Sitography]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks alot David!